# entity framework use old data and new data to check the unique constraints?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, constraints

I am using entity framework 4.0 and I have a table. In this table I have a unique constraint in one of the fields.

When I add a new register, I do the following:

1.- in the existing records, I recalculate the value of the unique field. This value depends on the new register that I want to add and change the value in all the registers.

2.- I calculate the unique field of the new record.

3.- I add the new register with the unique value.

In the moment in which I do the save changes, I check the values of the register I can see that in the unique field there are no duplicate values.

However, when I save the changes, I get an exception of unique value. This is because I change the value of one of the existing registers, change it and assign this value to the new record.

I thing that entity framework first add the new record and how other record still has the old value, I get the exception. wouldn't EF first update the existing records and then add the new record to ensure that compare the correct information?

Really what I guess is the normal bahavior of EF? If this true, how can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some code.

Comment: Why do you change an existing ID field? At least that is what I get from your question. If that really is necessary, I'd call SaveChanges directly after that before proceeding with the other entities.